# ¿Por qué no me funciona la secuencia de escape \r?

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
package Capitulo_2;

public class SecuenciaDeEscape {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hola Como \r Estas");
    }
}
```

Estoy usando Java JDK 8.

La secuencia de escape `\r` debería sobreescribir en la misma línea, pero salta a la siguiente.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Te invito a leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), y también a realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Deberías agregar el código en texto no en imagen. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como apuntas, `\r` debería mover el cursor al inicio de la línea, sobreescribiendo el texto que le precede, y así funciona en la mayoría de los IDEs pero, en el caso de Eclipse, es un conocido bug reportado en 2004, todavía sin arreglar. [Aquí](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936) tienes más información al respecto.

Si pruebas con, por ejemplo, NetBeans, verás que la salida funciona correctamente.

```
public class TesteandoPrint {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hola, cómo \r estás");
    }
}
```

> NetBeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias smt